# How to solve 2 variable recursion?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, discrete-mathematics, divide-and-conquer

T(m,n) = T(m-1,n) + T(floor(m/2), n-1)

**Base conditions**

T(m,n) = 1 when n = 0 
T(m,n) = 0 when m < n

**Edited:** Below is the code for which I want to know the time complexity in terms of m and n.

```
#Python3 program to count total number of  
#special sequences of length n where  
#Recursive function to find the number of 
# special sequences 
def getTotalNumberOfSequences(m,n): 

    #A special sequence cannot exist if length  
    #n is more than the maximum value m.  
    if m<n: 
        return 0

    #If n is 0, found an empty special sequence  
    if n==0: 
        return 1

    #There can be two possibilities : (1) Reduce 
    #last element value (2) Consider last element  
    #as m and reduce number of terms  
    res=(getTotalNumberOfSequences(m-1,n)+
         getTotalNumberOfSequences(m//2,n-1)) 
    return res 

#Driver Code 
if __name__=='__main__': 
    m=10
    n=4
    print('Total number
```

of possible sequences:',getTotalNumberOfSequences(m,n))

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to the original problem.

Comment: As a first step to solve the recurrence equation, please edit the question to list the first values of $T(m,n)$. For example, all $T(m,n)$ for $m, n\le 6$.

Comment: How do you interpret $m/2$ when $m$ is odd?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus we take floor of m/2 when m is odd.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Edited the question along with original code, could you please let me know what will be the time complexity of the above code?

Comment: It looks like it is not easy to find a tight bound for its time-complexity.

Comment: Note the asymptotic behavior of $T(m,n)$ and the time-complexity of the code are two totally different questions! For example, let $P(n)=2^n$. My algorithm: `def power(n): return 1 if n == 0 else power(n-1) * 2;` The asymptotic of $P(n)$ is $\Theta(2^n)$. My algorithm runs in $\Theta(n)$ time-complexity.

Comment: Please clarify in the question what is your question? Solving the 2-variable recurrence relations? Finding the asymptotic behavior of $T(m,n)$? Determining the time-complexity of the your code? These are three different questions. It is strongly preferred that you ask one question in one post.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I am concerned with time complexity of the code and now that you have mentioned, could you also explain me it's asymptotic behaviour(curious)?